# How to search the data in listview by more than one thing?

Tags: android, listview

Right now, my app filters the data in a listview when somethings is entered into the editText, but it can only filter by one thing at a time. I want it to be able to filter by more than value. For example, if someone types in "chicken" it should filter the recipes by the word 'chicken'. But, if someone then types in "dinner", I want it to filter the recipes by both "chicken" and "dinner." Eventually, I want to make it so those values appear as checkboxes above the listview so they can be easily removed.

I can't figure out how to do this. I played around with loops at first but didn't really get anywhere.

```
public class SearchActivity extends NavDrawerActivity {


    private DBHandler dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> filters = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String[] filters;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);
        // inflate the custom activity layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_activity3, null, false);
        // add the custom layout of this activity to frame layout.
        frameLayout.addView(activityView);

        dbHelper = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        //dbHelper.open();

        //Clean all data
        dbHelper.deleteAllRecipes();
        //Add some data
        dbHelper.insertSomeRecipes();

        //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
        displayListView();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void displayListView() {

        final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecipes();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                //DBHandler.COLUMN_CODE,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_NAME,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_TYPE,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_INGRED
        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[]{
                //R.id.code,
                R.id.name,
                R.id.type,
                R.id.ingredient,
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.recipeinfo,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String recipeName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipeActivity.class);
                //n.putExtra("position", position);
                n.putExtra("recipeName", recipeName);
                startActivity(n);
            }
        });

        //final GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        final EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.setImeActionLabel("Filter",1);
        myFilter.setPrivateImeOptions("actionUnspecified");
        myFilter.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == 1 || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    String filter = textView.getText().toString();
                    dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(filter);
                    filters.add(filter);
                    tv.append(filter);
                    myFilter.setText("");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchRecipesByName(constraint.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Then you start a new Activity via Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, RecipeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        // Or / And
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

fetchRecipesByName in DBHandler

```
public Cursor fetchRecipesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ROWID,
                        COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_INGRED, COLUMN_IMGPATH},
                null, null, null, null, null);

    }
    else {

        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ROWID,
                        COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_INGRED, COLUMN_IMGPATH},
                COLUMN_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'" + " or " +
                        COLUMN_TYPE + " like '%" + inputText + "%'" + " or " +
                        COLUMN_INGRED + " like '%" + inputText + "%'",
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the implementation of `dbHelper.fetchReccipesByName()`? I think, as of now, it queries the table only by one thing. You should change its logic and implement your complex need in this method (obviously, it should be an SQL query execution).

As a best practice, you should call `listView.setFilterText()` instead of `dataAdapter.getFilter().filter()`, because this method is supposed to run in secondary thread for the reason that DB queries are time consuming. If you call `listView.setFilterText()`, the framework will take care of threading and calls `filter.filter()` in secondary thread.

And finally, since you are searching by more than one keyword, but `setFilterText()` accepts only one `CharSequence` param, you should encode somehow many keywords into single `String` (say comma separated). And while querying you could decode the constraint to get the keywords.

Comment: If this description is not enough, comment here. I will attach some code.

Comment: I added the code for the fetchRecipesByName. But what if I wanted it so it searches the recipe results again after it was already search too? Like narrow the search results?

Comment: @Taylor It sounds complicated. Right now I don't have any best idea. May be I will answer in near future. Thank you.

Comment: But, if I were to do it the way you suggested, how I would I do that?